# Github clone repo message permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git, github, ssh, mediatemple

Having an issue cloning a github repo to my remote server (mediatemple).

Running

```
git clone git@github.com:uname/myrepo.git
```

In terminal while logged into my server gives me:

Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Right now I am able to connect via ssh from my machine to both my server and to github which I tested by running the check listed in step 5 - https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/.

Key has been added to my github account and has also been copied over to the server.

What am I missing here?

**UPDATE:**

Per Augusto's request here is the output when I ran the command.

```
    debug2: channel 0: written 90 to efd 7
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: close_write
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug2: channel 0: close_read
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r43 i3/0 o3/0 fd -1/-1 cc -1)

Connection to github.com closed.
Transferred: sent 3448, received 1976 bytes, in 0.2 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 16087.0, received 9219.3
debug1: Exit status 1
```

Comment: Run `ssh -vvv git@github.com`. That should output `Hi (YourUsername)! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.`. In your case it won't work, but the extra login will guide you to solve the problem. If the fix it's not obvious, please copy paste the last 20-30 lines in the question. **If ssh works, but git doesn't it means your git installation doesn't share the same ssh config as your git installation**

Comment: Note that "ssh -A" allows you to use your local key with your remote account.

Comment: @Augusto - see above for the output of the command you suggested.